# How to match on string length to get the data?

Tags: string, postgresql, sql-update, inner-join, sql-like

I have emp1 and emp2 tables. I am trying to update few values from emp2 to emp1 by mathcing emp_id. But the emp1 has correct emp_id where as emp2 has additional characters at the end. How do I match the emp_ids based on length of the characters( (Ex: if 3 characters in emp1 then match on first 3 chars in emp2, 4 characters in emp1 then match on first 4 characters etc.)

```
**TABLE: EMP1                                  TABLE2: EMP2**
    
EMP_ID  DEPT                                  EMP_ID      DEPT
                                            
AAA      Accounts                            AAA12        Accounts
BBBBB    HR                                  BBBBBrcp      HR
```

-Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the additional characters carry relevant information put them in an extra column. Otherwise drop them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join on `like`. It is unclear what you want to `update` in `emp2`, but the logic is:

```
update emp2 e2
set col1 = e1.col1, col2 = e1.col2  -- columns you want to update go here
from emp1 e1
where e2.emp_id like e1.emp_id || '%'
```

Beware that each employee in `emp2` should match on only one row in `emp1`, otherwise unexpected things may happen.